# Multiple arrays in javascript doens't work passing values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to create a multidimensional arrays in JS like this:

On my app.js file I have this

```
 var equipValue = new Array(); 
 var selectedTrucks  = new Array();
```

In my function.js file instead I have:

```
for (var i in selectedTrucks) {
    (function(i){
        // Simple Ajax request that return me a Json values
        var ajaxUrl = '/ajaxRequest/getSingleTruckPosition/' + selectedTrucks[i];

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxUrl,
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            if(data != null){
                //  equipValue doens't go. 
                // Unable to set property '0' of undefined or null reference
                equipValue[i] = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
             }
         });
```

Why I obtain: Unable to set property '0' of undefined or null reference ? 
Why that variables doens't work on my function.js file but selectedTrucks work perfectly?

Thanks guy

**EDIT**

Doing some test I've tried this:

```
 equipValue = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

So, the problem isn't scoope but create multidimensional array on Runtime? Or similar?

** EDIT 2**

Here the problem:

```
 var selectedTrucks     = new Array();
 // other 15 lines of codes and then this:
 if(selectedTrucks === undefined || selectedTrucks.length == 0){
        cleanMapMarkers();
    }
```

Why cleanMapMakers() is always launched even when selectedTrucks is empty?? All problems that I've found is here. 
Thanks

Comment: It's a simple arays like this: 

Selected trucks: 131-00004131, 132-00004132

Comment: Are you in strict mode? If not your edit means its implicitly creating a global variable which sadly doesn't prove its not a scoping issue. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2aqb3sa/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Update : seems equipValue is changed, or overwritten to a different type, somewhere else.

In your code, maybe you're looking for, if selectedTrucks is undefined OR if it's not empty

```
if(selectedTrucks === undefined || selectedTrucks.length != 0){
        cleanMapMarkers();
    }
```

---

- [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) parses json text to an object, but the callback already returns an object

---

```
.done(function(data) {
         if (data != null) {
           equipValue[i] = data;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dw74gk7j/

Comment: "Object doesn't support property or method 'bind' "...... With obviously the same precedent error..

Comment: Edge with last build of Windows 10. But doesn't work also with Chrome

Comment: Perhaps you need brackets for the `function() { ... }` part and then call `bind`

Comment: If i remove i form index: equipValue = jQuery.parseJSON(data); WORK..
So the problem isn't the scope but the array.... Javascript doesn't like create multi dimensional array on Runtime?

Comment: I do not mean this to sound rude but how can binding the `context` affect the `scope` of the function? `equipValue` isn't accessed from the context.

Comment: @bfmags I've tried your updated answer... But I have always the same error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of null

Comment: you'll have to use developer tools to debug it. see what the data response is, the value of i, the value of equipValue. the jsfiddle is working, maybe see what's different

Comment: The response of parseJson is a correct object with my data... i value is 0.... I've tried to override selectedTrucks (have no logic, but just to try and it work...

Comment: you mean by using selectedTrucks instead of equipValue, you're able to write to the array ? can you see the value of equipValue before the ajax call, see if it's accessible

Comment: Ok, I'm gettin crazy. I've tried adding a third variable above equipValue called "test". All work perfect. All work perfect with all names, but not equipValue. I have to check if somewhere equipValue is used.... No sense man

Comment: seems equipValue is changed, or overwritten to a different type, somewhere else

Comment: After 6 hours, I don't know why, I found ONE F***NG LINE OF CODE in one function that i never call that destroy equip value... No sense man, but thanks very very very much for your patience

Comment: I found the problem. I edited my question so, if you answers me i can put this answer "accepted"

Answer (score 0):

```
for var i in *object*
```

is used to iterate over an object properties.

So in `equipValue[i]` you seems to have `equipValue['131-00004131']` which is

```
equipValue = {
       131-00004131: 'your data'
}
```